# Passing a const double[][] array as argument to a double** interface

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, argument-passing

I have a 2-dim const double matrix which needs to be passed as argument to a function that takes a (non-const) double** parameter.

```
[CEqParams.h] // < given as is - can't do a thing about it

class CEqParams
{
public:
  void operator=(const CEqParams &right);  
  ...
  double dm_params[4][8];
};
```

.

```
[some_functions.h] // < dto.
...
void setEqParams(double **m);
...
```

.

```
[CEqParams.cpp]

void CEqParams::operator=(const CEqParams &right)
{
  setEqParams( « magic here » );
}
```

where `« magic here »` (in the final segment of code snippets) shall take `right.dm_params` (or an appropriate representation of its contents, respectively).

What else than manually transferring `right.dm_params` to an auxiliary `double**` structure (by means of a nested loop running over all array fields and copying them one by one) and then passing the latter to `setEqParams` could I do here?

PS: And given I'd be able to pass `right.dm_params` to a function that takes a `double[][]` (or `double[4][8]`?) as parameter - how would I get rid of the `const`? "Hint": A `const_cast<double[4][8]>(right.dm_parameters)` doesn't work.

Comment: why don't use implicit conversions?

Comment: A `double**` is _not_ a pointer to a 2D array. It is a pointer to [the first element in an array of] pointers.

Comment: @onof: `T[][]` is *NOT* the same as `T**`.

Comment: Frankly, this whole interface is dumb. Nobody sane in modern C++ would take a T**.

Comment: @DeadMG: The "some_functions.h" part is an almost 20yo old C header file - which hasn't been updated since then. The "CEqParams.h" part is a quick-n-dirty C++ abstraction of low-level routines from "some_functions.h" - which I'm not allowed to change. So: Yes, it's ugly.

Comment: It's not just ugly: it's _wrong_, and so is your interpretation of it.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: My interpretation of "it"? What are you referring to? (I didn't say a <code>double**</code> was _a_ pointer to a 2D array ...or did I?) - Elaborations are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One fairly ugly way, which at least doesn't require duplicating all the data, is to create a temporary array of row pointers, e.g.

```
void CEqParams::operator=(const CEqParams &right)
{
  double * dm_params_ptrs[4] = { dm_params[0], dm_params[1], dm_params[2], dm_params[3] };

  setEqParams(dm_params_ptrs);
}
```

Comment: Still, a problem remains: The dm_params[i], i=0..7 are of type const double [8]. A const_cast<double*>(dm_params[i]) might work here ...but that's actually worse than the current solution, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you will have to cast away the const-ness somehow (assuming that it is actually going to be treated as const ?).